# Mid 2012 MacBook pro, firmware lock

Tags: firmware-password

I was wondering if there was any way to remove a firmware password from a mid 2012 MacBook pro with USB or something. I just bought it off of Craigslist (sketchy i know but....) When it comes up all i get is a screen with blinking file with a "?" On it. And if i try and do recovery mode it goes to firmware lock, im wanting to get this unlocked and usable again but preferably without taking it halfway apart. Btw i have checked with Apple, unless i have the original proof of purchase (i don't), then they can't fix the issue for me. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're sure that it is actually a Firmware lock? A flashing question mark just means there is no valid OS on a disk that the Mac can find.

Obviously, there would be little point in a firmware lock if it could be easily bypassed. I think your first port of call should be contacting the seller and asking them for the password, with a view to getting your money back, if possible.

You're sure you can't access the Firmware Password Utility when booting to Recovery?

Some models will remove a firmware lock if the amount of RAM is changed. That's pretty much the only option. It's fairly easy to open the case and pull out some RAM.

Comment: It doesn't boot to recovery. It asks for a password with a lock on the screen. No options. And i was hoping to not have to fight the bottom panel off if possible. But can if need be